# Vue Server Side Rendering and Twitter Cards

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, twitter-card

Anybody have experience with twitter cards and Vue, dynamically loading meta tags into the components? seems like it needs server side rendering, does anybody know a way to avoid coding all the server side rendering? I am loading the meta tag information from APIs in Vuex and using them within my [vue-head](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-head)  meta function:

```
meta: function() {
      return [
        //twitter
        { name: "twitter:title", content: this.title, id: "t-title" },
        { name: "twitter:image", content: this.image, id: "t-image" },
        { name: "twitter:description", content: this.excerpt, id: "t-excerpt" },
        {
          name: "twitter:card",
          content: "summary_large_image",
          id: "t-card",
        },

        // Facebook / Open Graph
        { property: "og:title", content: this.title, id: "og-title" },
        // with shorthand
        { p: "og:image", c: this.image, id: "og-image" },
      ];
    },
```